# NetBeans platform Hint JavaFix API usage

Tags: netbeans-platform

I'm trying to create a NetBeans hint module that transforms a JUL log statement:

`LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Blah {0} Blah", param);`

to a Groovy log statement:

`log.info "Blah ${param} Blah"`

I have the hint appearing but I don't know how to use the `org.netbeans.spi.java.hints.JavaFix` API to perform the transformation:

```
    @Override
    protected void performRewrite(TransformationContext tc) {            
        WorkingCopy wc = tc.getWorkingCopy();
        TreePath statementPath = tc.getPath();

        //perform the required transformation ...
    }
```